# Passing imperative parameters through to Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the code below runs OK in Azure Functions on it's own and displays output. However the code is static, I need the URL (top line) to be able to be passed through as a parameter with an HTTP on-demand trigger.

The [article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#imperative-bindings) talks about Binding at runtime via imperative bindings, however it’s not 100% clear as to how to pass an HTTP based parameter e.g. https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/AustereoJustPlaying?url=legacy.scahw.com.au/2classicrock_128.xspf and then work with the parameter in the PowerShell code.

```
# Get the initial metadata for the stream
$url = 'http://legacy.scahw.com.au/2classicrock_128.xspf'
$iwr = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url

# Build up the .Net web client
$HttpCompletionOption = 'ResponseContentRead'
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
$webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('Icy-MetaData', '1')

# Get the Stream URL
$null = $iwr.InnerXml -match '<location>(?<location>.*)<\/location>'
$location = $matches.location
# Fire up the stream
$response = $webClient.GetAsync($location,$HttpCompletionOption)
$null = $webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove('Icy-MetaData')

# Pause until the stream title actually fires up
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

# Grab the song
$iwr = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url    
$null = $iwr.InnerXml -match '<title>(?<song>.*)<\/title>'

# Kill the stream
$webclient.Dispose()
# Output the song
$matches.song
```

Side note, if you get the error below on your computer…..

**New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded**

Run this block of code, seems that you need to ‘warm’ up the system in order to find the ‘type’, running Find-Type httpClient a few times seems to wake up the system to realise Yes, it does have this type installed.

```
function Find-Type ([regex]$pattern)
{
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes() | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Select-String $pattern
}

Do {
cls
$TypeSearch = Find-Type httpClient
} until ($TypeSearch -match 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default PowerShell HTTP Trigger template shows an example of that.

Query string parameters will be made available to your script as variables in the format `req_query_<parametername>`, so in your example above the URL parameter would be accessible using: `$req_query_url`

The following function is a simple example of just returning the parameter

```
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "URL parameter $req_query_url"
```

Comment: Yep thanks for that, i sort of worked it out later anyway when creating a new function, the default template itself has the info {# POST method: $req
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name 
}

Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"}